# Bash variable not working in http request/response body

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

object=$1
tenant=$2

server=$(sshpass -p 'password' ssh -tt root@ipaddress "/opt/something/sh/mysql -A 'admin_site' -e 'select id from something_servers where tenantcode=$2' | grep -o '[0-9]*'")

http -b "http://ipaddress/?app=something&t=users&v=users&server=$server&apikey=apikey&action=something.$1.list"
```

Everything seems to work fine. The value of variable $server is "24" as it should be. But still, when I call upon it in the http request it simply won't work... I honestly have no clue. I tested the variable's value by echoing it and it's correct. But for some reason when using it in the request it doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the `http` command? Did you intend to use `wget` or `curl`?

Comment: What do you see if you do `echo "http://ipaddress/?app=something&t=users&v=users&server=$server&apikey=apikey&action=something.$1.list"`?

Comment: Why are you using `$1` and `$2` instead of `$object` and `$tenant`? What's the point of assigning the named variables?

Comment: as an aside, you'll have to make sure that `$2` is properly escaped for use as a SQL string literal, and `$1` should also have to be URLencoded

Comment: I would run the script with `-x` turned on to see what is actually passed to your `http` command. If this looks fine, I would suspect an error inside the `http`-script (which you did not show). What is also strange (though not wrong): You set two variables (`object` and `tenant`) and never used them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates a variable called object and you set its value to the value stored in a variable called 1.

It creates a variable called tenant and sets it to the value of what's stored in the variable called 2.

It then creates a variable called server and then calls a subshell and runs the routine between $().

In the subroutine:

You use single quotes around

```
-e 'select id from something_servers where tenantcode=$2'
```

But for variable interpolation to work, you would need to use double quotes

Maybe that is your issue?

Comment: You'll find that the whole ssh command is double quoted, so the single quotes are literal and expansion still happens.